JsonForms can't handle too big of a payload
Was given a task to handle displaying custom JSON data via JSONForms.io library in React TS. Created everything needed, schema and ui schema, and added the data, and here comes the issue. My Chrome lagged (couldn't click anywhere, F12 not working).
So this lead to investigation on my end which resulted in seeing that one part of the JSON (lets call it propA) is too big, and when I comment out that propA part of the payload the rest of JSON is displayed as it should. I think its important to mention that propA is around 70% of the JSON payload (7k lines of 10k total)
Is there any way to optimize the library, the payload or to do anything else so I can display that JSON data in same/similiar form?
Here is the React TS code
export default function JsonViewer({ jsonData }: JsonViewerProps) {
return (
    <div className="h-full w-full">
        {jsonData ? (
            <div className="w-[100%] h-[100%] pt-2 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-100">
                <JsonForms
                    schema={temp}
                    uischema={uischema}
                    renderers={materialRenderers}
                    data={data}
                />
            </div>
        ) : (
            <p className="w-[100%] h-[100%]">Loading JSON...</p>
        )}
    </div>
);

and the parent components useEffect which gets the data
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const documentId = queryParams.get("documentId");

            if (!documentId) {
                console.error("Document ID not found in URL");
                return "";
            }

            const url = `http://localhost:7000/get-data/${documentId}`;
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {},
            });
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
            }
            const data: PdfResponse = await response.json();
            
            console.log(data)
            setJsonData(data.jsonData);

            const blob = base64ToBlob(data.pdfBase64, "application/pdf");
            const url_obj = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            setPdfData(url_obj);

            return data.pdfBase64;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    fetchData();
}, []);

Explanation here is that parent component via this useEffect gets the pdf and json data from BE and passes it to 2 child components which display it
